# Memory and excecution speed in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, memory-management

I am trying to create random lines and select some of them, which are really rare. My code is rather simple, but to get something that I can use I need to create very large vectors(i.e.: <100000000 x 1, tracks variable in my code). Is there any way to be able to creater larger vectors and to reduce the time needed for all those calculations?

My code is

```
%Initial line values

tracks=input('Give me the number of muon tracks: ');
width=1e-4;
height=2e-4;

Ystart=15.*ones(tracks,1);
Xstart=-40+80.*rand(tracks,1);
%Xend=-40+80.*rand(tracks,1);
Xend=laprnd(tracks,1,Xstart,15);
X=[Xstart';Xend'];
Y=[Ystart';zeros(1,tracks)];
b=(Ystart.*Xend)./(Xend-Xstart);
hot=0;
cold=0;

for i=1:tracks
    if ((Xend(i,1)<width/2 && Xend(i,1)>-width/2)||(b(i,1)<height && b(i,1)>0))
        plot(X(:, i),Y(:, i),'r');%the chosen ones!
        hold all
        hot=hot+1;
    else
        %plot(X(:, i),Y(:, i),'b');%the rest of them
        %hold all
        cold=cold+1;
    end
end
```

I am also using and calling a Laplace distribution generator made my Elvis Chen which can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13705-laplacian-random-number-generator)

```
function y  = laprnd(m, n, mu, sigma)
%LAPRND generate i.i.d. laplacian random number drawn from laplacian distribution
%   with mean mu and standard deviation sigma. 
%   mu      : mean
%   sigma   : standard deviation
%   [m, n]  : the dimension of y.
%   Default mu = 0, sigma = 1. 
%   For more information, refer to
%   http://en.wikipedia.org./wiki/Laplace_distribution

%   Author  : Elvis Chen (bee33@sjtu.edu.cn)
%   Date    : 01/19/07

%Check inputs
if nargin < 2
    error('At least two inputs are required');
end

if nargin == 2
    mu = 0; sigma = 1;
end

if nargin == 3
    sigma = 1;
end

% Generate Laplacian noise
u = rand(m, n)-0.5;
b = sigma / sqrt(2);
y = mu - b * sign(u).* log(1- 2* abs(u));
```

The result plot is

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you indicate, your problem is two-fold. On the one hand, you have memory issues because you need to do so many trials. On the other hand, you have performance issues, because you have to *process* all those trials.

Solutions to each issue often have a negative impact on the other issue. IMHO, the best approach would be to find a compromise.

More trials are only possible of you get rid of those *gargantuan* arrays that are required for vectorization, and use a different strategy to do the loop. I will give priority to the possibility of using more trials, possibly at the cost of optimal performance.

When I execute your code as-is in the [Matlab profiler](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/profile.html), it immediately shows that the initial memory allocation for all your variables takes a lot of time. It also shows that the `plot` and `hold all` commands are the most time-consuming lines of them all. Some more trial-and-error shows that there is a disappointingly low maximum value for the `trials` you can do before `OUT OF MEMORY` errors start appearing.

The loop can be accelerated tremendously if you know a few things about its limitations in Matlab. In older versions of Matlab, it used to be true that loops should be avoided completely in favor of 'vectorized' code. In recent versions (I believe R2008a and up), the Mathworks introduced a piece of technology called the JIT accelerator (Just-in-Time compiler) which translates M-code into *machine* language on the fly during execution. Simply put, the JIT accelerator allows your code to bypass Matlab's interpreter and talk much more directly with the underlying hardware, which can save **a lot** of time.

The advice you'll hear a lot that loops should be avoided in Matlab, is no longer *generally* true. While vectorization still has its value, any procedure of sizable complexity that is implemented using only vectorized code is often illegible, hard to understand, hard to change and hard to upkeep. An implementation of the same procedure that uses loops, often has none of these drawbacks, and moreover, it will quite often be *faster* and require *less memory*.

Unfortunately, the JIT accelerator has a few nasty (and IMHO, *unnecessary*) limitations that you'll have to learn about.

One such thing is `plot`; it's generally a better idea to let a loop do *nothing* other than collect and manipulate data, and delay any plotting commands etc. until *after* the loop.

Another such thing is `hold`; the `hold` function is *not* a Matlab built-in function, meaning, it is implemented in M-language. Matlab's JIT accelerator is not able to accelerate non-builtin functions when used in a loop, meaning, your entire loop will run at Matlab's interpretation speed, rather than machine-language speed! Therefore, also delay this command until *after* the loop :)

Now, in case you're wondering, this last step can make a ***HUGE*** difference -- I know of one case where copy-pasting a function body into the upper-level loop caused a 1200x performance improvement. *Days* of execution time had been reduced to *minutes*!).

There is actually another *minor* issue in your loop (which is really small, and rather inconvenient, I will immediately agree with) -- the name of the loop variable should not be `i`. The name `i` is the name of the imaginary unit in Matlab, and the name resolution will also unnecessarily consume time on each iteration. It's small, but non-negligible.

Now, considering all this, I've come to the following implementation:

```
function [hot, cold, h] = MuonTracks(tracks)

    % NOTE: no variables larger than 1x1 are initialized

    width  = 1e-4;
    height = 2e-4;

    % constant used for Laplacian noise distribution  
    bL = 15 / sqrt(2);

    % Loop through all tracks
    X = [];
    hot = 0;  
    ii = 0;          
    while ii <= tracks

        ii = ii + 1;

        % Note that I've inlined (== copy-pasted) the original laprnd()
        % function call. This was necessary to work around limitations 
        % in loops in Matlab, and prevent the nececessity of those HUGE 
        % variables. 
        %
        % Of course, you can still easily generalize all of this: 

        % the new data
        u = rand-0.5;

        Ystart = 15; 
        Xstart = 800*rand-400;
        Xend   = Xstart - bL*sign(u)*log(1-2*abs(u));

        b = (Ystart*Xend)/(Xend-Xstart);


        % the test
        if ((b < height && b > 0)) ||...
            (Xend < width/2 && Xend > -width/2)

            hot = hot+1;

            % growing an array is perfectly fine when the chances of it
            % happening are so slim
            X = [X [Xstart; Xend]]; %#ok

        end
    end

    % This is trivial to do here, and prevents an 'else' in the loop
    cold = tracks - hot;

    % Now plot the chosen ones
    h = figure;
    hold all
    Y = repmat([15;0], 1, size(X,2));
    plot(X, Y, 'r'); 

end
```

With this implementation, I can do this:

```
>> tic, MuonTracks(1e8); toc
Elapsed time is 24.738725 seconds.
```

with a completely negligible memory footprint.

The profiler now also shows a nice and even distribution of effort along the code; no lines that really stand out because of their memory use or performance.

It's possibly not the fastest possible implementation (if anyone sees obvious improvements, please, feel free to edit them in). But, if you're willing to wait, you'll be able to do `MuonTracks(1e23)` (or higher :)

I've also done an implementation in C, which can be compiled into a Matlab MEX file:

```
/* DoMuonCounting.c */

#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void CountMuons(
    unsigned long long tracks,
    unsigned long long *hot, unsigned long long *cold, double *Xout);


/* simple little helper functions */
double sign(double x) { return (x>0)-(x<0); }
double rand_double()  { return (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX; }


/* the gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int
        dims[] = {1,1};

    const mxArray
        /* Output arguments */
        *hot_out  = plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims, mxUINT64_CLASS,0),
        *cold_out = plhs[1] = mxCreateNumericArray(2,dims, mxUINT64_CLASS,0),
        *X_out    = plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(2,10000, mxREAL);

    const unsigned long long
        tracks = (const unsigned long long)mxGetPr(prhs[0])[0];

    unsigned long long
        *hot  = (unsigned long long*)mxGetPr(hot_out),
        *cold = (unsigned long long*)mxGetPr(cold_out);
    double
        *Xout = mxGetPr(X_out);

    /* call the actual function, and return */
    CountMuons(tracks, hot,cold, Xout);
}


// The actual muon counting
void CountMuons(
    unsigned long long tracks,
    unsigned long long *hot, unsigned long long *cold, double *Xout)
{
    const double
        width  = 1.0e-4,
        height = 2.0e-4,
        bL     = 15.0/sqrt(2.0),
        Ystart = 15.0;

    double
        Xstart,
        Xend,
        u,
        b;
    unsigned long long
        i = 0ul;


    *hot  = 0ul;
    *cold = tracks;

    /* seed the RNG */
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    /* aaaand start! */
    while (i++ < tracks)
    {
        u = rand_double() - 0.5;

        Xstart = 800.0*rand_double() - 400.0;
        Xend   = Xstart - bL*sign(u)*log(1.0-2.0*fabs(u));

        b = (Ystart*Xend)/(Xend-Xstart);

        if ((b < height && b > 0.0) || (Xend < width/2.0 && Xend > -width/2.0))
        {
            Xout[0 + *hot*2] = Xstart;
            Xout[1 + *hot*2] = Xend;
            ++(*hot);
            --(*cold);
        }
    }
}
```

compile in Matlab with

```
mex DoMuonCounting.c
```

(*after* having run `mex setup` :) and then use it in conjunction with a small M-wrapper like this:

```
function [hot,cold, h] = MuonTrack2(tracks)

    % call the MEX function 
    [hot,cold, Xtmp] = DoMuonCounting(tracks);

    % process outputs, and generate plots

    hot = uint32(hot); % circumvents limitations in 32-bit matlab

    X = Xtmp(:,1:hot);
    clear Xtmp

    h = NaN;
    if ~isempty(X)
        h = figure;
        hold all         
        Y = repmat([15;0], 1, hot);
        plot(X, Y, 'r');       
    end    
end
```

which allows me to do

```
>> tic, MuonTrack2(1e8); toc
Elapsed time is 14.496355 seconds.
```

Note that the memory footprint of the MEX version is slightly larger, but I think that's nothing to worry about.

The only flaw I see is the fixed maximum number of Muon counts (hard-coded as 10000 as the initial array size of `Xout`; needed because there are no dynamically growing arrays in standard C)...if you're worried this limit could be broken, simply increase it, change it to be equal to a fraction of `tracks`, or do some smarter (but more painful) dynamic array-growing tricks.

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you very much for your answer. It is very enlightening. Yet, I have some points to discuss. First of all the line 55 (`Y = bsxfun(@times, [15; 0], ones(size(X)));`) must have an error. I replaced it with `Y = bsxfun(@times, 15, ones(size(X)));` and it seems to be working. Secondly, while it is able to run many events it's much slower that mine, but I can live with that. Lastly, the plot that comes out is a straight line in `y=15` and it's not suppossed to be like that. It seems that the end points are missing. Apart from that, you are really a MatLab expert!

Comment: Any idea on how much will it take for `MuonTracks(1e29)` ?

Comment: @Thanos: Hey, I'm only human; it's very probable that I made a mistake somewhere :) Please feel free to edit/suggest edits when you find errors. BTW I did also get straight lines the first time I ran your function; this was not correct?

Comment: @Thanos: Regarding speed; the function I wrote is a very good candidate for compilation by embedded Matlab (`emlmex`), if you have Simulink/Fixed point toolbox. Just add the `%#eml` directive directly after the function declaration, and spend a bit of time on getting it compiled :) But for sure, once you manage to do that, the `mex` function will be a lot faster.

Comment: @Thanos: I was under the impression `X` was a 2xN matrix. The command `Y = bsxfun(@times, 15, ones(size(X)));` is essentially the same as `Y = 15*ones(size(X));`, but I thought you needed something like `Y = 15 15 15 15 ...; 0 0 0 0 ...];`. Oh well, "some debugging required" :)

Comment: The idea is that there are random lines from `y=15` to `y=0`, so they cannot be horizontal. I've never heard of `elmex`;I'll give it a search! `X` is suppossed to be `2xN`. the first row are the starting points(`y=15`) and the second row are the ending x-xoordinates(`y=0`).

Comment: @Thanos: That's what my original line was supposed to do...Why did it give you an error?

Comment: Which error do you mean? I'am not an expert but I believe the problem lies here: `[15;0]` should be `[15,1]` a scalar that is, which is equal to `15`. Something that I don't understand is how you implement the Laplace distribution. I believe that's the reason for plotting horizontal lines or perhaps points on `y=15`. However I tried to call `laprnd` inside your code, action that lead to memory errors...

Comment: Never Mind... I have just understood what are you doing. I checked it again and it's working! I've no idea what went wrong before, but the thing is that it's working!!! Now all what remains is to check `elmex`. Thank you sooooo much not only for your help, but for your enlightening information!

Comment: I did add `%#eml` after the function's decleration but I didn't any difference. `Muons(1e8)` took 62 seconds with/without `%#eml`... Perhaps I am doing something wrong. Just for the record I have 2008a...

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, it is sometimes faster to vectorize rather than use a `for` loop.  For example, this expression:

```
(Xend(i,1) < width/2 && Xend(i,1) > -width/2) || (b(i,1) < height && b(i,1) > 0)
```

which is defined for each value of `i`, can be rewritten in a vectorised manner like this:

```
isChosen = (Xend(:,1) < width/2 & Xend(:,1) > -width/2) | (b(:,1) < height & b(:,1)>0)
```

Expessions like `Xend(:,1)` will give you a column vector, so `Xend(:,1) < width/2` will give you a column vector of boolean values.  Note then that I have used `&` rather than `&&` - this is because `&` performs an *element-wise* logical AND, unlike `&&` which only works on scalar values.  In this way you can build the entire expression, such that the variable `isChosen` holds a column vector of boolean values, one for each row of your `Xend`/`b` vectors.

Getting counts is now as simple as this:

```
hot = sum(isChosen);
```

since `true` is represented by `1`.  And:

```
cold = sum(~isChosen);
```

Finally, you can get the data points by using the boolean vector to select rows:

```
plot(X(:, isChosen),Y(:, isChosen),'r');    % Plot chosen values
hold all;
plot(X(:, ~isChosen),Y(:, ~isChosen),'b');  % Plot unchosen values
```

**EDIT:** The code should look like this:

```
isChosen = (Xend(:,1) < width/2 & Xend(:,1) > -width/2) | (b(:,1) < height & b(:,1)>0);
hot = sum(isChosen);
cold = sum(~isChosen);
plot(X(:, isChosen),Y(:, isChosen),'r');    % Plot chosen values
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I was about to post a nearly identical suggestion

Comment: -1: @Dan: Because the answer starts with the completely outdated advice to avoid loops by default, and it does not mention the Matlab profiler and the best practices for performance optimization at all. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did replaced the if condition with the one you suggested but I get an error `??? Error: File: test.m Line: 18 Column: 18
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.`

Comment: @Thanos Can you post the code?  You shouldn't have replaced the `if` statement condition, the `if` statement should disappear entirely.  Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Fair enough, I'll be interested to read your answer.  A downvote seems somewhat harsh, though, since they are supposed to be indicate "an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" - my solution does answer the question, even if it doesn't do it quite as well as you would have liked.  Normal practice is to post your own answer and see if others agree that yours in the better one.

Comment: @Thanos I've updated the answer with the code as it should look.  Remove the line `hot=0;` and everything after it, and replace it with the above.  It works for me, except I found I had to modify the values of `width` and `height` to get any result.

Comment: @jazzbassrob: Perhaps I misunderstood! It did run, but it is far more slow, that what I did previous. My code for `tracks=10000` runs within a second while your takes a while(sth like 5 secs). Or perhaps I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @jazzbassrob: Never mind. I was probably doing something wrong. But the thing is that I can't see any difference. As far as the `height` and `width` are concerned, this is why I need to input many tracks (`>10000000`) but I can't do due to memoroy error. Any idea on that, which is actually what I care the most?

Comment: @jazzbassrob: It's nothing personal, but I find that the part on "or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect" applies to your blanket-statement "In Matlab, for loops are always particularly slow.". I can show you an arbitrarily large number of examples where the exact opposite is true, while your statement nowadays only applies to a comparatively small number of cases.

Comment: @jazzbassrob: Giving that (erroneous) advice to new (or experienced!) Matlab users will often cause them to write completely unintelligible and overly complicated code *just* to avoid a loop. IMHO, because of JIT, the *default* action should be to use the loop, unless the case is exceptionally trivial to do with vectorization and/or performance turns out to be an issue that can be mitigated/circumvented with vectorization.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Having re-read it, you're right about the first sentence, it was very misleading.  I've changed it now.  I was thinking of the answer I was planning to give and just wrote something to 'lead-in' to my answer without thinking much about it.  I think the rest of the answer is reasonable though, even if it is nowhere near a detailed as yours ;)